# Traceback from a Python Script: invalid literal

Tags: python, ascii, traceback

In short, what the Python script is supposed to do is to load and calculate ASCII type files.

With some previously pre-processed files, it works without errors, while with mine it throws an error. In any case, it looks as though my file is different from what it should be (input-wise).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\TER\Scripts python\PuissantPDI.py", line 124, in <module>
    for i in range (42, (42+(int(type_ncols)*int(type_nrows)))):
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nrows'
```

*It is not run in any QGIS/ArcGIS software, just from the cmd or IDLE.

**EDIT**

Just a small part of the code:

```
import sys 

print("\nPDI Processing...\n")

''' OPTION FILE '''

with open("options_PDI.txt") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]
option= []
for elem in content:
    option.extend(elem.strip().split(" "))
f.close()

b_type_file=option[1]
b_totalstage_file=option[3]
b_function_file=option[5]
b_state_file=option[7]
b_age_file=option[9]
b_material_file=option[11]
b_occstage_file=option[13]
landcover_file=option[15]
landuse_file=option[17]
transport_file=option[19]
```

---

```
print("Option file loaded...\n")

''' BUILDING TYPE FILE '''

with open(b_type_file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]
b_type= []
for elem in content:
    b_type.extend(elem.strip().split(" "))
f.close()

type_ncols=b_type[9]
type_nrows=b_type[19]
type_xll=b_type[25]
type_yll=b_type[31]
type_pixelsize=b_type[38]
type_nodata=b_type[41]

type_value=[]
for i in range (42, (42+(int(type_ncols)*int(type_nrows)))):
    type_value.append(b_type[i])

print("Building type file loaded...")
```

Comment: Either `type_ncols` or `type_nrows` is a string with the text `'nrows'`. My bet is on the latter. You'd have to share more code for us to tell you anything else.

Comment: Well exception error message is clear enough to understand that your file contains `nrows` string which can't be converted to integer value.

Comment: Oddly enough, I've taken a look in the ASCII files and they both have at the beginning `ncols` and `nrows`. I'll share more of the code in a bit.

Comment: So take a close look at the code and how it parses those files. We cannot tell you anything about what is going wrong here because you a) didn't share the code, and b) didn't share the file. Give us a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem and we could possibly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting on single spaces:

```
option= []
for elem in content:
    option.extend(elem.strip().split(" "))
```

You have an extra space somewhere, so all your offsets are off-by-one.

You could solve that by simply *removing the argument to `str.split()`. The text will then automatically be stripped, and split on *arbitrary width* whitespace. It won't matter if there are 1 or 2 or 20 spaces in the file then:

```
with open("options_PDI.txt") as f:
    option = f.read().split()
```

Note that I don't even bother with splitting the file into lines or stripping away the newlines.

Note that your treatment of the files is rather fragile still; you are expecting certain values to exist at certain positions. If your files contain `label value` style lines, you can just read the whole file into a dictionary:

```
with open("options_PDI.txt") as f:
    options = dict(line.strip().split(None, 1) for line in f if ' ' in line)
```

and use that dictionary to address various values:

```
type_ncols = int(options['ncols'])
```

Comment: Actually, that's true. I mean, in comparison to the other ASCII file that worked, the one with which I had trouble has on the first column for all rows an additional white space for no particular reason. That shouldn't have been generated. Thanks. Most likely that should be the problem. Now, somehow I'll have to figure out that part.

Comment: Would there be a way to ignore that by adding something to the script?

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong. I'm getting other errors. The thing is the `option.txt` is nothing more than a place from where paths and some parameters are being taken.

Comment: @Geosphere: I've added an alternative method of parsing the file; read the whole thing into a dictionary and use that to map options to values.

Comment: I can't seem to solve the problem. Apparently, I'm dumb enough to get a ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #10 has length 0; 2 is required

Comment: @Geosphere: you have an empty line; I've now limited it to only include lines with a space in it (meaning there is at least something to split on).

Comment: I'm getting an `IndexError: list index out of range, line 12, in <module>
    b_type_file=option[1].`

Comment: @Geosphere: that just means there are only 0 or 1 elements in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quote obvious here.

`'nrows'` *cannot* be converted to an `int`.

For some reason however you are calling this `type_rows` is not a string representation of a valid integer and seems to contain the string `'nrows'` instead.

---

For example:

```
>>> type_rows = "nrows"
>>> int(type_rows)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'nrows'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks I was getting all muddled up :)